# Need to create 3 ILB using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

The code works for creating one ILB but I need to create three ILB's using the following terraform code. but im unable to come up with the logic for count or for each.
like for example if i use 'for each' in module for ilb_name how do i refer the ip address and group manager using the same for each.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Terraform tf vars

```
ilb_name          = ["qat-rs-web","qat-rs-lb","qat-wi-web"]
project_id        = "cloudops-dev01-sb"

project_name      = "cloudops-dev01-sb"

region            = "us-east4"
#"us-west1"
subnetwork        = "cloudops-sb-sandbox-us-east4"
health_check_port = "4000"
ports             = [4000, 5000]
load_balancer_ip_name = "test-ilb-ip"


#instance-template
name_prefix  = "rs-instance-template"
instance_description = "rs instance template"
machine_type         = "n1-standard-2"
network              = "dev-shared"
subnetwork_project   = "dev-host"
compute_ip_address   = ["10.0.0.8","10.238.0.9","10.238.0.10"]
image_family         = "gold-centos-7"
source_image_project = "dev-tools"

group_manager_name = ["rs-web-igm","rs-lb-igm","wi-web-igm"]
base_instance_name = "qat-rs-app"
target_size        = "2"
```

modules/ilb.tf

```
data "google_compute_image" "default_image" {
  family  = var.image_family
  project = var.source_image_project
}
resource "google_compute_address" "load_balancer_ip" {
  project      = var.project_id
  name         = "load-balancer-ip-name-${var.project_id}"
  subnetwork   = var.subnetwork
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = var.compute_ip_address
  region       = var.region
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "instance_template" {
  name_prefix          = var.name_prefix
  instance_description = var.instance_description
  machine_type         = var.machine_type
  region               = var.region
  #foll.
  project = var.project_id

  labels = var.labels

  // boot disk
  disk {
    source_image = data.google_compute_image.default_image.self_link
    auto_delete  = false
  }

  network_interface {
    network            = var.network
    subnetwork         = var.subnetwork
    subnetwork_project = var.subnetwork_project
  }


}

resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "rs_igm" {
  name               = var.group_manager_name
  base_instance_name = var.base_instance_name
  region             = var.region
  target_size        = var.target_size
  project = var.project_id

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.instance_template.id
  }


  update_policy {
    type                  = "PROACTIVE"
    minimal_action        = "REPLACE"
    max_surge_fixed       = 4
    max_unavailable_fixed = 0
  }
  auto_healing_policies {
    health_check      = google_compute_health_check.tcp.id
    initial_delay_sec = 300
  }
}


# Forwarding Rule
resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "default" {
  name    = var.name
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  subnetwork            = var.subnetwork
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL"
  backend_service       = google_compute_region_backend_service.default.self_link
  ip_protocol           = "TCP"
  ip_address            = google_compute_address.load_balancer_ip.address
  ports                 = var.ports
  service_label         = var.name
}

# Backend
resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "default" {
  name                            = var.name
  project                         = var.project_id
  region                          = var.region
  protocol                        = "TCP"
  timeout_sec                     = 10
  connection_draining_timeout_sec = 10
  session_affinity                = var.session_affinity

  /* "backend" {
    for_each = var.backends
    content {
      description = lookup(backend.value, "description", null)
      group       = lookup(backend.value, "group", null)
    }
  }*/

   backend {
    group          = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.rs_igm.instance_group
    balancing_mode = "UTILIZATION"
  }

  health_checks = [google_compute_health_check.tcp.self_link]

}

# Health Check(s)
resource "google_compute_health_check" "tcp" {
  name    = "${var.name}-hc"
  project = var.project_id

  tcp_health_check {
    port = var.health_check_port
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
module "qat_hosted_pacs_ilb" {
  source = "../modules/load_balancer/"
  for_each = toset([var.ilb_name])
  image_family = var.image_family
  source_image_project = var.source_image_project
  project_id = var.project_id
  #load_balancer_ip_name = var.load_balancer_ip_name
  compute_ip_address = each.value.compute_ip_address
  region = var.region
  network            = var.network
  subnetwork         = var.subnetwork
  subnetwork_project = var.subnetwork_project
  
  name_prefix = var.name_prefix
  instance_description = var.instance_description
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  labels = var.labels

  group_manager_name = each.value.group_manager_name
  base_instance_name = var.base_instance_name
  target_size = var.target_size

  name = each.value.ilb_name
  ports = var.ports

  
}
```

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 8, in module "qat_hosted_pacs_ilb":
   8:   compute_ip_address = each.value.compute_ip_address
    |----------------
    | each.value is "cloudops-dev01-ilb"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 19, in module "qat_hosted_pacs_ilb":
  19:   group_manager_name = each.value.group_manager_name
    |----------------
    | each.value is "cloudops-dev01-ilb"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 23, in module "qat_hosted_pacs_ilb":
  23:   name = each.value.ilb_name
    |----------------
    | each.value is "cloudops-dev01-ilb"

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Im able to create one ilb, but im not sure how to create three ilbs, i can't think of the logic some direction or help would be appreciated

Comment: But there is no value assigned to the `ilb_name` variable?

Comment: Yes, sorry missed it, added it again. Thanks

Comment: Your `ilb_name` already has three values, and you use for_each. So again, what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are keeping `ilb_name`, `group_manager_name` and `compute_ip_address` as three different lists, instead of `for_each` it would be easier to use `count`:

```
module "qat_hosted_pacs_ilb" {
  source = "../modules/load_balancer/"
  count  = length(ilb_name)
  image_family = var.image_family
  source_image_project = var.source_image_project
  project_id = var.project_id
  #load_balancer_ip_name = var.load_balancer_ip_name
  compute_ip_address = var.compute_ip_address[count.index]
  region = var.region
  network            = var.network
  subnetwork         = var.subnetwork
  subnetwork_project = var.subnetwork_project
  
  name_prefix = var.name_prefix
  instance_description = var.instance_description
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  labels = var.labels

  group_manager_name = var.group_manager_name[count.index]
  base_instance_name = var.base_instance_name
  target_size = var.target_size

  name  = var.ilb_name[count.index]
  ports = var.ports  
}
```